# Add transition in responsive menu

Tags: html, css, transition, responsive

I'm trying to add a slide-down transition when the menu is 'opened' but i just can't get my head wrapped around it. Tried numerous things but can't get the transition to work.

I tried adding it to some of the classes with no result.
I read something about `display` blocking the transition and should be replaced with `visibility`. That results in two line's with the backgroundcolor and the dropdown button disapearing.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="home">Home</a>
        <a href="steppen">Steppen</a>
        <a href="walks" class="active">Walks</a>
        <a href="events">Events</a>
        <a href="agenda">Agenda</a>
        <a href="wij">Wie zijn wij?</a>
        <a href="tips">Tips</a>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
</div>  
            <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
              if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
              } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
              }
            }
            </script>
```

CSS:

```
.topnav {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #5bdeff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1% 2%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #5bdeff;
      color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
      background-color: #5bdeff;
      color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
      display: none;
} 

.topnav a:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.responsive.fa-bars {
    color:#000
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is completely unclear what kind of animation/effect  you want...

Comment: ah yes, that would be usefull. I want the menu to slide-down when the dorpdown-button is clicked. (edited the post)